# spring + mybatis, how to share database connection in a http request

Tags: spring, mybatis

In my web application, I am using spring + spring-webmvc + mybatis, and a jndi datasource is used.

I created a mvc controller to handle user's login request.

In the controller, I need to accomplish some database related tasks, each task will access a service object which have mybatis mapper auto wired by spring, this will create a mybatis sqlsession and use it and close it.

my question is, can we make all those task share the same mybatis sqlsession ?

From what I understand, a mybatis sqlsession means a jdbc connection involved.

I don't want to waste any resource.

**edit :**

```
here is the logging message in the real example of my application:
19:26:29.959 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
19:26:29.959 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@c1c7c4] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
19:26:30.001 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction - JDBC Connection [jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:6001/cmp, UserName=SA, H2 JDBC Driver] will not be managed by Spring
19:26:30.002 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.codingfarm.cwe.sys.mappers.UrlRoleMapper.countByExample - ==>  Preparing: select count(*) from CMP.PUBLIC.SYS_URL_ROLES WHERE ( URL = ? ) 
19:26:30.002 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.codingfarm.cwe.sys.mappers.UrlRoleMapper.countByExample - ==> Parameters: index.jsp(String)
19:26:30.008 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.codingfarm.cwe.sys.mappers.UrlRoleMapper.countByExample - <==      Total: 1
19:26:30.008 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@c1c7c4]
19:26:30.008 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
19:26:30.009 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@37c7ee] was not registered for synchronization because synchronization is not active
19:26:30.010 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction - JDBC Connection [jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:6001/cmp, UserName=SA, H2 JDBC Driver] will not be managed by Spring
19:26:30.010 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.codingfarm.cwe.sys.mappers.UrlRoleMapper.countByExample - ==>  Preparing: select count(*) from CMP.PUBLIC.SYS_URL_ROLES WHERE ( URL = ? and ROLE_ID in ( ? , ? ) ) 
19:26:30.011 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.codingfarm.cwe.sys.mappers.UrlRoleMapper.countByExample - ==> Parameters: index.jsp(String), system(String), basic(String)
19:26:30.012 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.codingfarm.cwe.sys.mappers.UrlRoleMapper.countByExample - <==      Total: 1
19:26:30.012 [http-8080-3] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@37c7ee]
```

**edit:**
according to mybatis-spring documentation:

*SqlSessionTemplate is the heart of MyBatis-Spring. It implements SqlSession and is meant to be a drop-in replacement for any existing use of SqlSession in your code. SqlSessionTemplate is thread safe and can be shared by multiple DAOs or mappers.*

Then how to make several mappers share one SqlSessionTemplate ?

Comment: If you are defining your SqlSessionTemplate as singleton (which is the default) bean, then all your mappers should automatically share that one instance. Just tried it by injection various mappers and yes, they all have a reference to the same SqlSessionTemplate. Are you perhaps defining your SqlSessionTemplate as a Prototype?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to use `SqlSessionFactoryBean`.

If you have a definition like this

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:myBatisConfig.xml" />
</bean>
```

You can then define mapper bean one by one

```
<bean id="userMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
  <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.yourcompany.youapp.mapper.SomeMapper" />
  <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Or use `MapperScannerConfigurer` to instantiate all of them by scanning your mapper classes

```
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.yourcompany.youapp.mapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Then mybatis session will be created per spring transaction and used by all instantiated mappers.

Comment: Using the mybatis:scan feature will auto-inject the factory or template, too, but yes, I prefer to define the mappers explicitly, tool. See: https://mybatis.github.io/spring/mappers.html#scan

Comment: bu I am looking for a way to share mybatis session for mappers those do non-transactional operations.

Comment: Ok that was not very clear from the question. Do you really need this? Mybatis SqlSession is very lightweight. Initialization of mybatis configuration and opening new connections - that's what takes time. Configuration creation should be done once (and it is done once if you use mybatis-spring). To amortize connection creation use connection pool.